# getting landscape and portrait view in android tab

Tags: android

I am working on android. How to get landscape and portrait view in android tablet ?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific asking questions. This question doesn't give me a clue what are you exactly mean by that.

Answer (score 1):

If you rotate your tablet to landscape, then you get the landscape view, otherwise you get the portrait view.

Answer (score 0):

in the emulator, use KEYPAD_7 (or Ctrl-F11) and KEYPAD_9 (or Ctrl-F12) to cycle through the layout orientations.